# Can someone explain this Python syntax?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am working with Pyramid for Python and there are several files that have the syntax below. I'm very new to Python, and none of the 3 books I have read so far mention this format.

```
[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
```

My guess is that it's a way of creating a list named logger_sqlalchemy.

```
logger_sqlalchemy = [level:INFO, handlers:'', qualname:sqlalchemy]
```

Is this what the code is doing?

Comment: The text you have shown is not valid Python syntax. Perhaps it's a configuration file that is read by a Python program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a Python file, but a logging configuration file. See [logging config file format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-fileformat).

Comment: Thanks that clarified it for me.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax appears to be completely off. However, if you appear to have ascertained it correctly, it would not be a list, because that raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> logger_sqlalchemy = ['level':'INFO', 'handlers':'', 'qualname':'sqlalchemy'] 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    logger_sqlalchemy = ['level':'INFO', 'handlers':'', 'qualname':'sqlalchemy']
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Instead, it would be a *dictionary*:

```
>>> logger_sqlalchemy = {'level':'INFO', 'handlers':'', 'qualname':'sqlalchemy'} 
>>> logger_sqlalchemy['handlers']
''
>>> logger_sqlalchemy['level']
'INFO'
>>>
```

Comment: You mean, "instead, it will be a *dictionary*"

Comment: Edited to fix that, if you were the downvoter, please undownvote?

Comment: I was not but I'll give you an upvote to compensate. It's good for python beginners to learn the difference between lists and dictionaries.